# Android.mk not linking system library libandroid.so

Tags: android

In my android 2.3 project , i am using the native asset manager. In the docs it says add the 
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid to the android.mk file which I have

but the linker is giving the following error saying it can't find it

> /android-ndk-r7/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: cannot find -landroid

I've compiled a sample in the NDK with the same library and that works so I can't understand why a different project is giving this problem

Comment: turned out I needed to target a later platform 2.3

Comment: Better put that as an answer to your question. That's the way it works on SO. In due time you can accept the answer as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

turned out I needed to target a later platform 2.3